# Is an iPod touch 2nd Gen still a viable option for simple iOS Development?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

My Friend is trying to sell off some of his old tech and I'm thinking of buying his iPod touch 2G for development purposes, is it still supported in any way (i.e. will I find any dev kits that will build to it)?

Comment: [_"The second generation iPod Touch cannot be upgraded beyond iOS version 4.2.1."_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch) Do you intend to write apps that you can only test on a rather outdated platform?

Comment: That kinda answered my question thank you :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a 2nd gen iPod touch is only useful if you wish to download old versions of Xcode and you only want to learn 2-year old iOS app development.

If you want to learn modern iOS development then you need an iOS device that runs iOS 6.0 or later. This requires at least a 4th gen iPod touch, iPad 2, or iPhone 3GS.

Comment: ...or the iOS simulator.

Comment: But the simulator has so many limitations. It's fine for some basic learning but to do anything really useful requires a real device.

Comment: I assume you mean an iPhone 3GS; since the iPhone 3G never even got iOS 5.

Comment: Thanks guys, guess Ill hold off on the iPod and iOS dev until Apple sort out their pricing issue then (bound to happen, iOS is losing market share like a falling meteor since iPhone 5 so they need to get back into their competitive shoes).